# Get timeline method in rtweet package returns this error: Error: API did not return json

Tags: rtweet

I am trying to get timeline using rtweet package. Search tweet is working but get timeline is not working.

Here is my code:

```
tweet_msnbc = get_timeline(user = 'MSNBC', n=2000)
```

It returns:

```
Error: API did not return json
```

It worked just last night. And now it's not working anymore!

I also tried:

```
token <- get_token()
tweet_msnbc = get_timeline(user = 'MSNBC', n=2000, token=token)
```

But got the same error.

Please help.